How to read <?Insert-Table ID="hebz-9780192893512-chapter-1-tableGroup-1"?> tag from Xml file using XDocument in C#
In xml file have tags start with <?. I try but not able read those tag by using
reading xml file tags
how to read xml tags
I used System.Xml.Linq.XDocument to read xml file. I unable to read  tag how to read this tag. i used XDocument

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
All within the question as text, no images.

item.Name.LocalName

These "tags" are called processing instructions and in Linq they are represented using the XProcessingInstruction class.
